# Harvard math 55 materials

Tags: reference-request

I would like to know what Harvard math 55 go through.So can anyone please point me to their course and their problem sets ?Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The Wikipedia article links to some problem sets/course notes (look at the last 3 links): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_55#External_links

Comment: From the Harvard 55ers I've talked to, the problem sets do not take nearly the advertised amount of time.

Comment: @AlexBecker could it just be they are very smart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information for 2011 is at http://www.math.harvard.edu/~siu/math55a/

---

**Update** (Feb 2020)

As mentioned in the comments, the original link doesn't work any more. Here are two alternatives

- [Math55a, Fall 2017](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M55a.17/index.html)
- [Math55a, Fall 2008, including notes and homeworks](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/55a/08/html/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, but how do I use them?Do you think that those homework assignments are self-contained and have enough theory needed to solve the problems?

Comment: You asked for someone to point you to the problem sets. I did that. Now it seems that wasn't what you really wanted. When you have made up your mind as to what question you actually want to ask, you can edit your question accordingly. In any event, to find out whether the assignments have enough theory to solve the problems, why not try to solve the problems and see for yourself?

Comment: Sorry for asking that.You fairly exploded. Sorry again.(I see the point.Maybe I should try to do them first myself)(I was just asking as you do seem very experienced)

Comment: I am fairly explosive. Please don't take it personally.

Comment: Surely I won't. :D

Comment: Currently (May 2015), the information page for 2001 for Harvard's "Math 55" that Gerry Myerson pointed to, in his answer here (posted 3 years ago, on May 2012) is returning a 404 Not Found Error. Here's the link to the "Fall 2010" page: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M55a.10/

Comment: It appears that nowadays one needs a Harvard login just to view material about Harvard courses, unless the lecturer has posted information on his/her own website.